# checking the bool property of multiple objects simultaneously

Tags: c#, wpf

I have multiple check boxes on my GUI application that enables auto update for each object of the same type. So if the checkbox is checked, the isautoupdate property is set to true else set to false. I have a button that needs to enable/disable auto update on all checkboxes.  How do I go about checking if isautoupdate property of all the objects is set to true or false.

my current implementation is using a foreach loop that iterates through each object and checks if the isautoupdate is set to true or false but I get a toggle effect where if some checkboxes are checked it will uncheck them and vise versa.

in .cs

```
foreach (MxL_GUI_ChannelSettingAndStatusItem item in theGUIManager.theDevice.channelCollection)
{
    if (!item.IsAutoUpdated)
    {
        item.IsAutoUpdated = true;
    }
    else
    {
        item.IsAutoUpdated = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want your slave checkboxes to toggle then don't write code that toggles them. Instead, check the `IsChecked` property of the master checkbox and apply the value to all `IsAutoUpdated` properties of your items:

```
foreach (MxL_GUI_ChannelSettingAndStatusItem item in ...)
{
    item.IsAutoUpdated = masterCheckbox.IsChecked.Value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, I ended up going with a master checkbox instead of a button and your solution works great thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand you requirement exactly.  If you want to detect if all items are set to true or false then use:

```
var items = theGUIManager.theDevice.channelCollection;

// If you need to know if for all items IsAutoUpdated = true
bool allChecked = items.All(item => item.IsAutoUpdated);

// If you need to know if they're all false
bool noneChecked = !items.Any(item => item.IsAutoUpdated);
```

Then update your items, e.g:

```
foreach(var item in items) { item.IsAutoUpdated = !allChecked; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution Phil. Why did you declare noneChecked if you not using it in the code?

Comment: Just because you asked how to check if all objects were set to true OR false.